# No adapter for endpoint

Tags: java, spring, endpoint

I have a Java class with the @Endpoint annotation.  It was working fine until I try to add another parameter - MessageContext and I am getting the "No adapter for endpoint"

See my method signature below:

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart = "PolicyNewBusinessQuoteRequest", namespace = TARGET_NAMESPACE)
  @ResponsePayload
  public PolicyNewBusinessQuoteResponseDocument processQuoteRequest(@RequestPayload PolicyNewBusinessQuoteRequestDocument requestDocument, MessageContext messageContext) throws Exception {
}
```

Comment: can you add few more details? its soap?can you show request class

Answer (score 0):

Your data is not sufficient to answer this question.

But most of the times,

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No adapter for endpoint […]: 
Is your endpoint annotated with @Endpoint, 
or does it implement a supported interface like MessageHandler or PayloadEndpoint?
```

this exception is can be resolved with

Addition of @XmlRootElement annotation on your request and response class.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.  It was all working fine until I added another parameter - the MessageContext object.

Comment: When I added the org.springframework.ws.context.MessageContext parameter, I started getting this error.  Is there anything to be done when adding additional parameters.  Spring docs says it is automatically enabled for MessageContext

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution to my own problem:

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/web-services/126322-unable-to-include-and-access-messagecontext-on-endpoint-method

Comment: thats good, please accept your answer so that this question moves to answered section